# Qt 4.6 and OpenGL: how to capture keyboard presses with three different widgets at once?

Tags: c++, opengl, qt4, qt-creator

I created a form in Qt Creator, and added three custom QWidgets (all are the same class called Renderer) into the form. I want all of the three widgets besides the form to get notified when a user presses the Alt key, but I cannot even get one to work at the moment.

I added the void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *) and void keyReleaseEvent(QKeyEvent *) into the Renderer class, but the functions are not called at all... (breakpoints were not triggered) The key press functions are protected.

```
void Renderer::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event) {
    switch(event->key()) {
    case Qt::Key_Alt: {
        isAltPressed = true;
        cout << "alt got pressed" << endl;
        break;
    }
    default:
        break;
    }
}

void Renderer::keyReleaseEvent(QKeyEvent *event) {
    switch(event->key()) {
    case Qt::Key_Alt: {
        isAltPressed = false;
        cout << "alt released" << endl;
        break;
    }
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Am I missing something here?

Also, is there anything special I have to do in order to have keyboard presses registered by all three widgets at the same time?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Answered. For the second part of the question, I fixed the problem by making isAltPressed a class variable instead of a private member variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's your [`focusPolicy`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#focusPolicy-prop)?  Keyboard events will only go to the widget with focus (you can then call the other handlers yourself).

Comment: I haven't worked with focusPolicy before, and honestly haven't even heard of it (for Qt) until now... can you kindly give me a link to find out more about this?

Comment: Link added.  I've very little experience with Qt myself, but that rule about keypress events going to the window with focus is pretty much universal.  When I saw that the default policy is "no focus", I thought it was worth suggesting you double-check.